# ng-repeat does not update the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I am new to Angular and need your help on an issue with the `ng-repeat` of my app.

**Issue:**
I have an html page (`event.html`) and in the corresponding controller of the file, I make a request to a firebase collection and update an array (`$scope.events`). The issue is that the data from firebase takes a few seconds to load and by the time data arrives to `$scope.events`, `ng-repeat` has already been executed and it displays an empty screen. The items are displayed correctly the moment I hit on a button in the HTML page (`event.html`).

**Sequence of events:**
I have a login page (`login.html`) where I enter a user name and phone number and I click on the register button. I've configured this click on the register button to go to the new state (`event.html`).

Here is the controller code for `login.html`:

```
$scope.register = function (user) {
    $scope.user = user.name;
    $scope.phonenumber = user.phonenumber;

    var myuser = users.child($scope.user);

    myuser.set({
        phone : $scope.phonenumber,
        Eventid : " ",
        name : $scope.user
    })
    var userid = myuser.key();
    console.log('id is ' +userid);
    $state.go('event');
}
```

The controller of `event.html` (the state: `event`) has the following code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://glowing-torch-9862.firebaseio.com/Users/Anson/Eventid/");
var eventref = new Firebase("https://glowing-torch-9862.firebaseio.com/Events");
var myevent = " ";
$scope.events = [];

$scope.displayEvent = function (Eventid) {
    UserData.eventDescription(Eventid)
    //UserData.getDesc()
    $state.go('myevents');
    //console.log(Eventid);
};
function listEvent(myevents) {
    $scope.events.push(myevents);
    console.log("pushed to array");
    console.log($scope.events);
};
function updateEvents(myevents) {
    EventService.getEvent(myevents);
    //console.log("success");
};

ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        $scope.id = childSnapshot.val();
        angular.forEach($scope.id, function(key) {
            eventref.orderByChild("Eventid").equalTo(key).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                myevents = snapshot.val();
                console.log(myevents) // testing 26 Feb
                listEvent(myevents);
                updateEvents(myevents);
            });
        });
    });
});

$scope.createEvent = function () {
    $state.go('list');
}
```

`event.html` contains the following code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Events">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button" ng-click="createEvent()">Create Event</button>
        <button class="button" ng-click="showEvent()">Show Event</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header padding">
        <div class="list">
            <ion-item align="center" >
                <button class= "button button-block button-light" ng-repeat="event in events" ng-click="displayEvent(event.Eventid)"/>
                {{event.Description}} 
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The button `showEvent` is a dummy button that I added to the HTML file to test `ng-repeat`. I can see in the console that the data takes about 2 secs to download from firebase and if I click on the 'Show Events' button after the data is loaded, `ng-repeat` works as expected. It appears to me that when `ng-repeat` operates on the array `$scope.events`, the data is not retrieved from firebase and hence its empty and therefore, it does not have any data to render to the HTML file. `ng-repeat` works as expected when I click the dummy button ('Show Event') because a digest cycle is triggerred on that click. My apologies for this lengthy post and would be really thankful if any of you could give me a direction to overcome this issue. I've been hunting in the internet and in stackoverflow and came across a number of blogs&threads which gives me an idea of what the issue is but I am not able to make my code work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but in React what I do for Firebase is listen for data via something like `ref.on('value', functionToExecuteWhenLoaded())`

I'm not sure if that's possible in Angular, but I think the solution to this would be to use the `ref.on()` method to listen for data, and then have the `ng-repeat` fire.  Again, total Angular noob, but maybe someone has a code example for you.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, Angular supports the ref.on method. I've changed my code to ref.on instead of ref.once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you update your events array call `$scope.$apply();` or execute the code that changes the events array as a callback of the `$scope.$apply` function

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.events.push(<enter_your_new_events_name>);
})
```

Comment: Thank you antoniskamamis!!. The $scope.apply worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working outside of controller scope, like in services, directive, or any external JS. You will need to trigger digest cycle after change in data.

You can trigger digest cycle by

`$scope.$digest();` or using `$scope.$apply();`

I hope it will be help you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to delay the binding time. Use $timeout function or ng-options with **debounce** property in your view.

you have to set a rough time taken to get the data from the rest API call. By using any one of the methods below will resolve your issue.

**Method 1:**

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
myapp.controller("DIController", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.callAtTimeout = function() {
        console.log("$scope.callAtTimeout - Timeout occurred");
    }
    $timeout( function(){ $scope.callAtTimeout(); }, 3000);
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
// in your view
<input type="text" name="userName"
       ng-model="user.name"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```